# What does the carat (^) operator do on Django Q objects?

Tags: django

The [Django Query documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) mentions three operators which can be used to combine `Q` objects:

> `Q` objects can be combined using the `&`, `|`, and `^` operators.

But the examples in the docs all focus on `|` (which is maybe understandable).

The `&` and `|` operators are (to me at least) fairly obviously analogous to `AND` and `OR`.

But what does `^` translate to in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a **XOR** operator, so it means the first condition needs to be true, or the second, but not both.

Not all SQL servers support a XOR operator itself, but that is not necessary. If we have a `X ^ Y`, that is equivalent to `(~X & Y) | (X & ~Y)`

so imagine that we have: `Q(is_drunk=True) ^ Q(is_driving=True)`, this can boil down to a query with:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE (NOT is_drunk
       AND is_driving)
  OR (is_drunk
      AND NOT is_driving)
```

Comment: I've seen a case where this generates SQL like `1 = (CASE WHEN <bool> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN <another_bool> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + ...`. Not sure whether this is relevant to this answer or not.